# Automatically include declaration files of libraries outside of node_modules in Typescript Angular cli project

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Angular Project that has a lib folder for cases where a node_module needs to be modified. I'm able to connect the lib folder with using tsconfigs paths options and actually **can compile** the application to run without errors. The problem is that vscodes tslint still won't recognize the lib folder.

[image]

The lib folder is in the root of the project:

```
root/lib/ng2-smart-table
```

The tsconfig setup for the project is:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],
      "@lib/*": [
        "../lib/*"
      ],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/*.ts",
    "../src/**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.ts",
    "../lib/**/*.ts",
  ]
}
```

There is also a public repo if you want to download a basic example of this problem. Link: https://github.com/Jonathan002/tslint-cannot-find-module-example

What can I do to remove the lint error in vscode?

Comment: Did you try restarting the ide?

Comment: Yes I've restarted it multiple times. Does the sample project work without the lint errors for you?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Below config file is working for me. Have a look at the paths, have done a bit modification:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],

      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../src/*.ts",
    "../src/**/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/@nebular/**/*.ts",
    "../lib/**/*.ts",
  ]
}
```

Comment: What version of typescript and tslint are you using? I've tried your config with typescript@2.7.2 and tslint@5.10.0 and I'm still getting the cannot find module error.